# Do I need to do something special to use the replace method with symbols?

Tags: java, string

Here's some code

```
private String replaceToEncrypt(String password) {
    password.replace('A','@');
    password.replace('E','=');
    password.replace('I','!');
    password.replace('J','?');
    password.replace('O','*');
    password.replace('P','#');
    password.replace('R','&');
    password.replace('S','$');
}
```

Using print statements its seems that nothing happens because ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
before this method is ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ after

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to re-assign the result of each replacement, for example:

```
password = password.replace('A','@');
```

This is because all Strings in Java are immutable, and any operation that modifies a String what really does is return a new String with the modifications, the original String is kept unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen that.

Answer (score 1):

`replace()` according to the Java 7 API:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of
>   oldChar in this string with newChar.

So in your code you need to reassign to password the new String:

```
password = password.replace('A','@');
//etc...
```